# С помощью регулярного выражения привести строку к нужному виду

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть функция *php*, которая возвращает строку:

```
<span class="posted_in"> <a href="#" rel="tag">Назад: Название категории</a></span>
```

Я же от неё хочу получить строку такого вида

```
<a href="#" class="posted_in" rel="tag">Назад: Название категории</a>
```

т.е. удалить `span` и перенести `class="posted_in"` в ссылку.

Как это правильно сделать с помощью регулярного выражения?

Comment: Правильно сделать это с помощью регулярного выражения нельзя. Правильно - это с помощью [DOM](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php).

Comment: Регулярки для разбора html/xml лучше не использовать. Можно, конечно и микроскопом гвозди забивать, при должном рвении реально. Но чревато эммм... и код разбить, и руки порезать. Смотрите в сторону DOM, различных XML/HTML парсеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace("/<span class=\"posted_in\"> <a href=\"#\" rel=\"tag\">(.*)<\/a><\/span>/", "<a href=\"#\" class=\"posted_in\" rel=\"tag\">$1</a>", $str);
```

Comment: что-то не получается заменить. вы на 100% уверены, что ваша запись правильная?

Comment: не получается перенести таким способом ссылку, если она такого переменного вида `href="http://cite.ru/catalog/picca/"` а не просто "#"

Answer (score 1):

```
'<span class="posted_in"> <a href="#" rel="tag">Назад: Название категории</a></span>'
.replace(/<span\s+(class=(["']?).*\2)\s*>\s*<a\s+(href=(["']?).*\4)\s+(rel=(["']?)tag\6)\s*>(.*?)<\/a>\s*<\/span>/, "<a $3 $1 $5>$7</a>")
// "<a href="#" class="posted_in" rel="tag">Назад: Название категории</a>"
```

PS: Это на js, но регулярка должна подойти и для php.

---

Для многострочных надо заменить `.` на `[\s\S]`.

Comment: спасибо @Qwertiy , но в данном случае скрипт - это костыль

Comment: @Вася, прочитай PS ;)

Comment: если подставлять в `php` то там этот кусок
`(href=(["']?)[\s\S]*\5)\s+(rel=(["']?` не принимает..

Comment: @ReinRaus, а что не так с этой регуляркой для php?

Comment: @Вася, ну захардкодь кавычки, если они у тебя гарантированно есть.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '<span class="posted_in"><a href="#" rel="tag">...</a></span>';
$allowed_tags = "<a>";

echo strip_tags($string, $allowed_tags);
```

ps. про "перенести класс" я не дочитал, видимо.